# Whats the best way to update data foreach-category from url?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am developing an application for /reddit. Users can add favorite subredits.

How can i update all subredits.

Currently im thinking about

`for(RedditCategories rd : categories) { 
MyTask task = new MyTask(this, rd.Url);
task.execute().get();`

which is the worst scenario. very bad practice.

Another way is to pass next task to current task `MyTask task = new MyTask(this, rd.Url, new MyTask(this, rd+1.url, null)`

and i will execute the next task on onPostExecture method

Any better way for multiple calls?

Comment: As a [service in the background](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html).

Comment: So inside `onHandleIntent` i will have a foreach loop that make http request. `foreach(Category cat : categories) { list.add(getHttpContent()) }` ... right?